# Работа с файлами в symfony2

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony2, csv

Всем привет! Я столкнулся с такой задачей: есть массив с n вложенностью. Нужно этот массив записать в  csv файл, чтобы была структура типа:

- строка 1

  - подстрока1

    //.....
  - подстрока2

    - подподстрока1

    //.....
- строка2

// ......

Вот я ищу полезные книги и информацию, как это можно реализовать. Буду благодарен, если вы подскажите, где "рыть". Также буду очень благодарен если подскажите какие-то книги (для новичков) по Angularjs (опционально), только не судите строго, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Comment: Это скорее дерево вот та статья которая может тебе в этом разобраться http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html

Comment: @Dima Kaukin, спасибо большое, очень полезная информация!